# Playing a sequence of audio files in background

Tags: objective-c, ios, background, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

In my app i have an instance of **AVAudioPlayer**, that plays a sequence of mp3's ,switching to the next one by `initWithData`:

I want to let the user continue listening to the player even if he switchs off the screen or goes to the background. I know, that i can use `remotecontrolevents` to switch to the other audio when the user taps it, but can i make it switch automaticly,just like in iPod player?

Comment: Do you mean once the current track is finished?

Comment: Yes,i store urls to audio files in core data objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` protocols. First include it in your interface:

```
@interface MyAppViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {
    AVAudioPlayer   *yourPlayer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *yourPlayer;
```

Then in your implementation:

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
//This method is called once the file has finished playing
//Insert code here to play the next file
}
```

Don't forget to set the `delegate` of `yourPlayer` to `self` in your `viewDidLoad` method (or where ever you decide to put it):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents)]){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
        [self becomeFirstResponder];
    }

    self.yourPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] init];
    self.yourPlayer.delegate = self;
}
```

You'll also need to change **Required Background Modes** in your *info.plist* to **App plays audio**

Don't forget to unregister the remote control events (`viewDidUnload`):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents]
```

Comment: Are you sure, that **didFinishPlaying** will be called if i'm in the background and i can access managedobjects there?

Comment: `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` will be called in the background providing you set the above mode in your .plist file, and also call `beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents` (Note, some may put the Audio session initialisation and remote control events in `viewDidAppear`). There's a thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185621/is-it-possible-to-test-ios4-multitasking-background-music-playing-on-the-simulat/3243857#3243857) with more info.

Comment: Works great on the simulator vut soen't work on the real device at all-don't you know why it could be like this?

Comment: What is the problem when testing on the device?

Comment: It just stops playing,no matter if i go to the home screen or turn off the screen.Maybe i have to add something more in some plist?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.crocodella.com.br/2011/01/using-avplayer-to-play-background-music-from-library/)

Comment: Thank you, i just didn't add Required Background Modes,only **UIBackGroundModes**.Now,eveything works fine!