# How to play audio when Application enters in to the background using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, background-process

I am new to iphone.I am working on audio player which is used AVAudioPlayer.By using this framework i develop one application it plays the song when the application in active state but whenever i click home button in iphone it will immediately stops the audio in background but the application is running in background how to listen the audio when application is in background.
If any body know this please help me..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to test iOS4 multitasking/background music playing on the simulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185621/is-it-possible-to-test-ios4-multitasking-background-music-playing-on-the-simulat)

Answer (score 0):

In the `info.plist` add key name `Required background modes, Item 0 - App plays audio` and when you are start to play audio add below code.

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];

NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryError];
```