# Playing Stream Audio with MPMoviePlayerController in Background Modes

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

my first question here...

I have been searching how solve this issue i start a app using monotouch creating my MPMoviePlayerController like this:

```
this.mp = new MPMoviePlayerController(new NSURL("http://stream3.dyndns.org:1935/iphone/xeco.stream/playlist.m3u8"));
this.mp.useApplicationAudioSession=false //also try with true
this.mp.PrepareToPlay();
this.mp.Play();
```

Everything works great, i hear the audio

Notes:

**I already search how fix this and on my plist file add UIBackgroundModes and string audio as many members advice**. (Using the plist editor provided in monotouch). Also add this code to set the category of my audio session:

```
AudioSession.Initialize();
AudioSession.Interrupted += delegate{
Console.Writeline("interrupted");
}
AudioSession.Category = AudioSessionCategory.MediaPlayback; //also try ambientsound and others
```

**The problem is:**

How can i keep the audio playing when the app goes background, when the device blocks or the home button is pushed?

The stream always seems get muted when press home or block the device, when i return to the app the audio starts very quickly wich make me think that the app is streaming all the time but only doesnt hear.

I am testing only on the Iphone Simulator, i am starting to think that maybe this is caused only on simulator. any advice?

thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I receive my licenses of monotouch and my register on the iOS Dev Program, so i test my app on the device. It works, the important part is on the AudioSession part:

```
AudioSessionCategory.MediaPlayback;
```

and when use the player on:

```
this.mp.useApplicationAudioSession=false
```

Comment: I hit this same problem over the weekend.  I do not believe that you can test background audio on the simulator.  It will work if you deploy that app to a device.  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185621/is-it-possible-to-test-ios4-multitasking-background-music-playing-on-the-simulat) is a related link.  Also [here](https://github.com/bholmes/IOSSampleApps/tree/master/avTouch/avTouchCSApp) is sample app I am creating which is an extension of Apple's avTouch sample.

Comment: Thanks for the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185621/is-it-possible-to-test-ios4-multitasking-background-music-playing-on-the-simulat seems thats only a problem with the simulator. I hope this week can test on a real device i will update this question with the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I receive my licenses of monotouch and my register on the iOS Dev Program, so i test my app on the device. It works, the important part is on the AudioSession part:

```
AudioSessionCategory.MediaPlayback;
```

and when use the player on:

```
this.mp.useApplicationAudioSession=false
```

The app works great on the device. Monotouch rules!