# Keep UIWebView playing music while App is in background

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview

I think everything is in the title.

I have a UIWebiew that plays music, and when the user use the power or home button, putting the app in background, I want the music to keep playing.

Is it possible ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't actually do this with a UIWebView, but you can still do it. This method still streams the audio off of an online resource via a URL. Here is some code to help you. Now, lets say, you want to stream the audio when the app exits for a video, then its very similar, but uses the MediaPlayer framework instead of AVAudioPlayer framework.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://website.com/audio.mp3"];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];

[audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: This other post may help you make the AVAudioPlayer play music in the background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185621/is-it-possible-to-test-ios4-multitasking-background-music-playing-on-the-simulat/3243857#3243857

Comment: Thank you Chris, but I don't think it will work, because I do not open a .mp3 in the UIWebView, in fact, I play music on soundcloud. The user access to a list of soundtrack and can launch one.

Comment: There is probably an audio file linked to the soundcloud's html5 audio player. check the source of the website, and see where it connects to, to get its audio files to feed into the html5 audio player

Answer (score 3):

A little tricky but it is possible.  From the official Apple doc below:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1668/_index.html

You need to first declare in your plist the `UIBackgroundModes` for `audio`, and then write the following code snippet in your `AppDelegate`

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
BOOL success = [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryError];
if (!success) { /* handle the error condition */ }

NSError *activationError = nil;
success = [audioSession setActive:YES error:&activationError];
if (!success) { /* handle the error condition */ }
```

Now when you have audio playing from a UIWebView, you can go to the home screen, change to another app, or lock the screen and the audio will continue playing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible, and even after checking `UIWebView`'s documentation I only found the following three attributes related to media playback.

```
  allowsInlineMediaPlayback  property
  mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction  property
  mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay  property
```

Unfortunately, none of them do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You need to do:

1. Activate playback session:

`@import AVFoundation;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];`

2. Add audio background mode in your Info.plist:

Required background modes: App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay

`<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>`